rrule with exdate and until
I'm using rrule.js library with the rrulstr as follow:
const rrule = rrulestr(
        `DTSTART:20190610T103000\nRRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20190801\nEXDATE:20190618T103000Z\nEXDATE:20190619T103000`
    )


it does exclude the dates according exdate but there is 2 problems :

rrule.options.dtstart is not as in the recurrence string , it is according current time
rrule.options.until is null

** when removing the exdate from the recurrence string the dtstart and until are as excpecting
what am I missing ? I know that exdate is not property of rrule but I'm doing as described in documents

Try to replace your code like this:
const rrule = rrulestr(
    `DTSTART:20240801T000000Z\nRRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;UNTIL=20240901T000000Z\nEXDATE:20240820T000000Z,20240830T000000Z`
)

Please ensure that the DTSTART & UNTIL has same timezone you should make it correct
